# getting Nullpointer exception warning android for getResources()

Tags: android

How can I replace this to not get nullpointer warning and why

```
if(lblSchemeName.getCompoundDrawables()[2] != null && lblSchemeName
                        .getCompoundDrawables()[2].getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_mf_arrow_up).getConstantState())
```

I am getting null pointer exception for getResources() please help me guys

Comment: Add a null check around it

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE its inside if check like I am checking whether it is equal to some thing

Comment: Thats obvious, Its the least thing you need to worry about. It returns null when your app is force closed by the android processor. To be double sure, you can put that block of code in try catch block

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I got the answer finally I replaced

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_mf_arrow_up).getConstantState()
```

with these

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.icon_mf_arrow_up).getConstantState()
```

And it actually worked since ContextCompat is Helper for accessing features in Context introduced after API level 4 in a backwards compatible fashion.